# Unable to connect Teradata V14 using Teradata SQL Assistant from Windows 7

Tags: teradata

I installed Teradata V14 for VMWARE on my Windows 7 (64 bit) Machine. Then I installed .Net provider, ODBC driver (Both 64bit and 32bit) on my Windows to Connect Teradata using Teradata SQL Assistant.

But when I try to connect Teradata from SQL Assistant I get the error **Teradata Server is not accepting connections**.

I tried ping from my windows to VMWARE Suse linux where Teradata is installed. I get the response. But only when connecting thru SQL Assistant I am unable to.

I defined the Data source and all configurations as mentioned in Teradata forums. Still I couldnt connect.

Pls help.

Note : Teradata is working fine in VMWARE. I am able to access only in VMWARE using BTEQ, Not from Windows using SQL Assistant.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help much with your problem, but I happened to be in contact with the developer of SQL Assistant on another matter and passed the link to this question to him.  For some unknown reason, he was not able to register directly on Stack Overflow but he did send me this response:

> The message they are getting indicates that Teradata is not running on
>   that system. The system itself is running but the database is not
>   started. It makes no sense that BTEQ can connect if they are getting
>   that error message from SQL Assistant, at the same time. My guess is
>   that the database came up, or went down, between their tests.

As the message says, the Teradata system is not accepting connections.  If you happen to be logging onto the same system where Teradata is installed, perhaps that is why you can connect with BTEQ.  There may be some Teradata system setting that needs to be enabled that allows a network connection.

Your best bet is to contact your local Teradata administrator (whoever installed it).